# WPF XAML: How to; assign a dynamic variable to a gradientstop value

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a drawing brush declared in XAML and the brush works fine is it possible to assign a dynamic variable for the color value of a GradientStop?

Like    "{DynamicResource execl_1}"

```
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="Column_B_GRAD">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.4" RadiusX="0.6" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.4,0.4">
                            <GradientStop Color="#ffffe1" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#f8e737" Offset="0.461"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#e79b00" Offset="1"/>
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0 1,1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" SpreadMethod="Pad">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#39FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0 1,0.5" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: It would have taken you less time just to try this than to post the question here.

Comment: I get the error 'dynamic resource cannot be resolved'

Answer (score 0):

Use SolidColorBrush  as below and define key

SolidColorBrush x:Key="ReadOnlyTextBrush" Color="#FFFFC154"

TextBox Foreground="{DynamicResource ReadOnlyTextColor}"